# PHP Output Buffer "Millenium" Bug?

Tags: php, buffer, flush, minimum, output-buffering

I faced a strange issue today.

For several months I used buffer flushing in PHP to send small string sizes to the client without problems.

Today I returned to the project and it turned out that my server won't send strings smaller than 512 bytes.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "length:".$myUpcomingStringSize;
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(1);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($allLines); $++) {
        echo $allLines[$i];
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
?>
```

This code worked like charm the whole last year. And now it doesn't anymore. I played around a bit and added some random characters. As the string size gets equal or greater 512, the server sends the buffer content.

Can anybody imagine the issue I have to solve here? Anyone else facing this issue? Or does 
someone know how to configure this minimum packet size?

Comment: have you tried a different client?

Comment: Kind of. I used the same client all the time. But actually I'm programming in Objective-C so I'm getting the raw data without side-caching or anything like that

Comment: The iOS network stack will very likely have buffering though. You should make sure your lines end in newlines (`\n`)

Comment: Thanks for the newline hint. Didn't help though :(

Comment: The strange thing is that the servers behavior changed suddenly. I had no problem until now…

Comment: Maybe server config changed? `mod_gzip` for example will of course buffer its output

Comment: It's the strange thing. We didn't change anything with the server. It stands in office as before…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed neither the program nor the server, you should assume that the program never worked as intended. Especially Windows systems are known to buffer the output until a certain number of Bytes is in the output buffer. This buffering is at system-level and thus can not be affected by any PHP configuration.

If you know that 512 Bytes is the minimum required for the output buffer to send, then you could use something like

```
define('MIN_OUTPUT_LENGTH', 512);
echo str_pad("length: $myUpcomingStringSize", MIN_OUTPUT_LENGTH, "\0"), '\n';
// (If you run into trouble with the null-bytes, use space character instead)
```

### Notes

- If you do not use "userspace" output buffering, then `ob_flush();` is redundant.
- If there is no delay in your `for` loop, then flushing between lines is not a good idea. Especially for mobile applications where the network tries to pack as much data as possible into a single packet.
- There is a syntax error in your `for` loop header (The expression `$++` is missing a variable identifier, probably `i`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not working on a Windows system… But I assume your right. It might have worked by accident :) The `$++` was just just a typo, I think you have one too: `), '\n'`. `str_pad()` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Julian No typo there (unless I missed another), you can separate strings in the `echo` statement by a comma like `echo "a", "b", "c";` this is valid PHP ;)

Comment: Really?! Haha, I didn't notice that :) Another question: You said flushing in a loop is not a good idea. I did that to increase the amount of packages sent to the client so that I can measure the progress more precisely. Why isn't that a good idea?

Comment: In the code you wrote in your question there is no real delay between the lines, all you do is echo an array of strings, this is almost instant. However if you flush in between (and it actually gets sent) you will probably end up with worse performance. You should only influence the output buffer if you really **really** have to and there is no way around. (like in `echo $some; flush(); sleep(1)`, unless you want the client to wait a second for `$some`)